# Rails 4 nested fields_for not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, nested-forms

I see many posts, but I am not sure they apply to my problem.  Mainly because when I try to implement those solutions I get syntax errors.  I don't know why this seems to be such a problem.

I have profile object that has a 1:1 relationship with user.  In the edit of profile I want to save the email of user. But it will not save here is the code and output...

View:

```
              = semantic_form_for @profile do |f|
                = f.inputs class: "form-group" do
                  = f.input :name, input_html: { class: "form-control" }
                  = f.input :username, input_html: { class: "form-control" }
                  = f.semantic_fields_for @profile.user do |u|
                    = u.input :email, input_html: { class: "form-control" }
```

The paramaters being passed to the controller:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"iMkkLX6qN7PagmbnEQlQZ0CH5Q/fl+G9273eHFO9aRk8EG4MisEi3PwQOWocU2wp3UW5ju4DOJcUh5v19pS46A==", "profile"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "username"=>"JohnnyD", "user"=>{"email"=>"jdoe@email.com"}, "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"profiles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"4"}
```

The response from the controller:

```
Unpermitted parameter: user
```

The whitelisting:

```
params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :username, :user)
```

The models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I have tried adding users_attributes: [:email] to the required params #syntax error.
I have tried adding user: [:email] to the required prarams #syntax error
I have tried with and without accepts_nested_attributes in the model #no effect.

Can someone clue me in, because I am clearly clueless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

First - `= f.semantic_fields_for @profile.user do |u|` Should be:

`= f.semantic_fields_for users do |u|`

(Here you are telling Rails to pick related Database table, so should be plural `users`)

And second - strong params should really be as you already tried:

`params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :username, users_attributes: [:email])`

Hope it fixes your issue.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but the whitelist now gives me a syntax error, which is what I was getting any time I tried to make these changes.../home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:95: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...s: [:email]

Comment: The full whitelisting line... params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :name, :about, :country_code, :state_code, :city, :avatar, :company, :company_url, :username, users_attributes: [:email], :online_store_url, :facebook_url, :instagram_url, :blog_url, passion_ids: [])

Comment: I moved the users_attributes to the end of the white list and stopped getting the syntax error, but now I get this in the form...undefined local variable or method `users' for #<#<Class:0x007f64f5cc7f70>:0x007f64dc020d58> because I removed the @profile.user reference and replaced it with users.

Comment: I found the answer, looks like the :id symbol has to be included in the attributes.  I followed this link and it solved my problem, you were a big help for me working through it J.D. so I am giving you the credit.  The link: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: Thanks for sharing! And yes, :id had to be included... Glad it helped